# Salesforce Data entry event does not work

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, visual-workflow

I'm trying to build a journey with a Salesforce Data entry event.
I want to trigger the journey every time a new Service Appointment (Lightning Scheduler) is created or an existing one is changed.

I followed all the steps in Journey Builder, a new DE is automatically created, the SFDC Flow is automatically created, but when I create a new record, nothing goes through.

At first I thought it had something to do with entry criteria, so I removed all criteria for test purposes. Still nothing happened.

I tried it with inserting the related Contact. Also tried it with related PersonAccount... nothing.

Does anybody have experience with creating a journey triggered by a Lightning Scheduler Service Appointment? Or can anybody tell me how I can debug this properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the below guide helpful for troubleshooting Journey Builder Integration issues using the debug logs.

https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/10/09/troubleshooting-journey-builder-integration-with-debug-logs/

The below documentation lists some other things you can check, such as making sure the OAUth Token for the integration is valid.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316536&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1